# How to translate "Automatic transmission" and "Manual transmission"

Tags: перевод, одним-словом, сокращения

Please help me translate **automatic transmission** and **manual transmission**.

I found this:

- **automatic transmission**: автоматическая коробка передач
- **manual transmission**: механическая коробка передач
- **transmission**: коробка передач

Is that correct?
Are they abbreviated as **АКП** and **МКП**?
If I use these abbreviations on a Russian website, will everybody understand them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Механическая коробка передач* and *автоматическая коробка передач*  are indeed the correct translations. The abbreviations *МКП* and *АКП* are also correct (also sometimes used are *МКПП* and *АКПП* - *механическая/автоматическая коробка переключения передач*), although I haven't seen these outside of motor-engineering literature.

In colloquial speech, you'll also hear simply *механика* and *автомат*.

As for your specific website, I suppose it depends on your audience.  I personally would avoid using the abbreviations, but it's really up to you.

Comment: _Трансмиссия_ for _transmission_ also works.

Comment: Another colloquial word for manual transmission is "ручная коробка".

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's correct.

Also correct:

**automatic transmission:** автоматическая коробка **переключения** передач

**manual transmission:** механическая коробка **переключения** передач

**transmission:** коробка **переключения** передач

and they're abbreviated as **АКПП** and **МКПП**

Also:

**automatic transmission:** автомат

**manual transmission:** механика
[image: http://ab.onliner.by/]